# Merging Visual Studio XML documentation files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with 2 projects. A model and a webapi project.

I need to be able to merge the 2 documentation files (XML documentation file - setting inside build properties) into one. Can visual studio handle this or do I need to have a custom build event take care of this?

I have never needed to this kind of thing before so not sure really where I should start to look.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!